# Google Sheets filter formula get specific columns, plus between two dates

Tags: google-sheets

I am building somewhat of an invoice report tool where I would like to pull all of Client X's orders between the dates set in A1 and A2, but I only need 6 of the 35 columns.

So far I am able to use the =filter formula with ease but I get all the columns of course, and I have no idea how to only filter based on the dates in A1 and A2.

If my sample data is below, I want to be able to pull all records for Client 1, between the dates set in A1 and A2 and only show Col1, Col3, and Col 6 in my "report"

```
Row   Col1       Col2     Col3        Col4             Col5            Col6
1     Client 1   $45.00   01/15/2016  123 Main Street   404-989-9999   John
2     Client 1   $75.00   01/17/2016  123 Main Street   404-989-9999   John
3     Client 3   $15.00   01/18/2016  456 Park Street   404-989-9999   Sue
4     Client 4   $35.00   01/18/2016  111 East Street   404-989-9999   Chris
5     Client 5   $95.00   01/19/2016  789 North Street  404-989-9999   Tim
6     Client 3   $65.00   01/20/2016  456 Park Street   404-989-9999   Sue
7     Client 3   $25.00   01/21/2016  456 Park Street   404-989-9999   Sue
8     Client 1   $45.00   01/22/2016  123 Main Street   404-989-9999   John
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you have a hidden column that returns true if the date is between a1 and a2, and then just creat a pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be the use of query()

```
=query(A2:F, "select A, C, F where A='Client 1' and C >= date'"&text(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date '"&text(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' " ,0)
```

Change ranges to suit.

Another way (with filter) would look something like this:

```
=filter({A2:A, C2:C, F2:F}, A2:A="Client 1", C2:C >= A1, C2:C <= B1)
```

I hope that helps ?